# How to scroll UITableView background view when scroll the table

Tags: uitableview, view, background

I know the UItableView have a property named:backgroundView,  but this view not scroll with the table,  I want add a background after the table, and can scroll .

How can I do that.

Thanks very much.

Comment: setting backgroundView to your UITableView which has scrolling functionality should fill up the background for the whole tableview

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the background image via backgroundColor property of UITableView:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

Comment: What if it's needed to place two UILabels on background view? I don't think this is approachable way, unless you need to use an image as a background view.